# Process HTML files like PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, include

I've been trying to get .html files to process like .PHP files, using the [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file. I've used the following, both of which don't work and trying to access the test page gives me an option to download a file that doesn't exist. How can I fix this?

I tried both of these;

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

The *idea* is to allow includes in my web pages, but still using .html files.

Below is some more code from my .htaccess file, I don't think it's messing with the addType, but I'll post it up.

```
## Hide .html extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

[1&1 IONOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1%261_Ionos) have decided to only allow me to do it with the following code;

```
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .html .htm
```

Comment: You need to add `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`

Comment: This also helped me, for some reason the host LCN also decided to be difficult and only allowed "AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .html .htm". I'll be recommending my clients move away!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Comment: @Switchfire Try it without your `.htaccess` to test. Pretty sure that's where the problem could be. This should have worked, I use it myself. Delete `.htaccess` temporarily or disable it.

Comment: @Switchfire Also try adding `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm` but I doubt that will make a difference.

Comment: I disabled it and used a new clean .htaccess file, still deosn't work, I'm using a .html file with an echo in it, nothings happening though. Could it be my host?

Comment: @Switchfire Is your `.html` file setup as `<?php echo "Hello"; ?>` ? and it could be your host. Have you tried using an actual file with the `.php` extension?

Comment: Yep that's how the file is setup, Using a .php file works, I guess I better get on to my host then!

Comment: @Switchfire Yes that's a good idea. Maybe your host is blocking added `.htaccess` functionality. Just to be 100% sure, create a test `.htaccess` file with `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` in it only.

Comment: @Switchfire Plus if you have access to `php.conf` then you can try putting it in there to see. Depends on how much permissions/freedom your host gives you. You can try seeing what options are available to you in Cpanel if that's what you have to administer your site.

Comment: This worked, Hunted down a few other versions of the handler AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .html .htm

Comment: @Switchfire Ah... that's great news! Right on, glad it worked out. :-)

Comment: Cheers for the help, I think it's because this site is hosted with 1and1 their a very odd company, I'll accepted this anwser to help anyone else with a similar problem! Thanks again ;)

Comment: @Switchfire I'm definitely going to make a note of that one. It's good information to keep on file. I guess it depends on the server's configuration. I've never seen the `x-mapp` version before.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

or

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

or

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

or

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php5
</FilesMatch>
```

**Edit:**
For 1&1 server:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .html .htm
```

One of these should work

Comment: @Switchfire and this: AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm

Comment: Do you even have the necessary access rights to add a Handler in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes I have full access, I believe it's because of the hosting company, I've added the code that works to my orignal post. Thanks.

Comment: @Switchfire I forgot to mention this. 1&1 only works with that.

Comment: @Don thank, this => AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm worked for me, I'm using SuPHP at KnownHost

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below also.

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

OR

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to know whetheryou are using php-fpm instead of php module. If you are using php-fpm, then you have to do two things:

1) in httpd.conf add the lines:

```
<FilesMatch \.(html)$>
    SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

2) in php-fpm.d/www.conf make sure you have the line

```
 security.limit_extensions =
```

This will work. Maybe there are better settings, I don't know. I do know that if you have php-fpm, none of the answers involving AddHandler, AddType are going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, editing `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` with following directive in php-fpm config file fixed the issue for me.

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .html
```

I was on a Unix based OS with Nginx + php-fpm, and I was getting `Access denied.` when browsing for an `.html` file

I checked the Nginx log files, but the log files had nothing to identify the issue, but found the cause of the issue to be following Nginx location block

```
location ~ \.html$ {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    ...
}
```

On macOS, my php-fpm config file was located at `/usr/local/etc/php/8.1/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

On a Debain OS the config at `/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

If that didn't help, you can use one of following methods to search for the config file

```
find -name "php-fpm.conf" -o -name "www.conf"
locate php-fpm.conf
```