# Linux web hosting server equivalent code for Windows ASP #Include file statement

Tags: linux

My web hosting company uses Linux servers and that means they do not use ASP.

Question for the Linux pros. I need a comparable statement of the ASP #Include filename server side include that will work with my Linux hosting package from by hosting company.

I want to use the include to drag in HTML code into another HTML file and have it assembled into one HTML file for delivery to the browser, just like the #Include statement does.

ASP is HTML code and all I have to do to use it on a Windows based server is change the index.htm name to index.asp. This allows me to the insert an #include in each of my 80 website pages in place of the header code.

This allows me to change the top portion of all my web pages (menus structure, logos, etc.) by changing just one HTML file. Sweet!

Can Linux do that without a huge bunch of complex code?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely running php, so you can use

```
<?php include 'filename.html' ?>
```

. But it's also probably configured only to parse .php files. So you either need to change your files to be .php or configure your php handler to process .html files.

Comment: Interesting. So I change the .htm to .php. But what PHP code do I use to substitute for the asp include? And any comment on where and how to configure my PHP handler? I do have PHP options in my on-line hosting account panel.

Comment: sorry, it was in there, but i didn't realize it was filtered out

Comment: I found the PHP include code and changed the extensions to .php. I also found the PHP settings in my on-line web hosting panel and selected PHP 5.5 for one of my domains as a test. It said it could take awhile to configure. I'll get back later with the progress.

Comment: The PHP 5.5 configured, but no options to change things. The browser code shows the PHP command was not processed (nothing brought in the the head.php file to the index.php file, but the web page does display the index.php page. But the include process was no processed. I did click on "see php,ini setting" in the control panel, but nothing resembling extensions or handler, and nothing could be changed. I will try tech support at my host to ask them.

Comment: This should be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397957/htacess-process-html-files-like-php

Comment: I did try changing the include file extensions to head.htm, head.php, and head.inc, but no processing occurs. I made sure I also changed the filename link to them in the index.php file.