# .htaccess Process html files like php

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, apache2.4

I've been trying to get .HTML files to process like .PHP files using the .htaccess file on my localhost. I've used the following one by one,

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .html .htm

AddHandler application/x-mapp-php55 .php .html

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5-script .html .htm
```

But none of the above worked for me.

I am using php5.5 and apach 2.4 in xampp

Is there any other configs in apache config file?

Need help

This question is clear, but no proper answers yet given. It seems nobody can answer it. Too bad, but it can happen

Comment: Please take a look at the answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4687217/743512

Comment: @Chris still not working. I restarted `apache` after each change, cache cleared but its not working.

Comment: Try with: `AddHandler php-script .htm .html`

Comment: @Croises tried but not works again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process HTML files like PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397957/process-html-files-like-php)

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me in the past.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
```

Also note that you must have `mod_mime` activated in Apache.

Also I assume your server is allowing the use of an .htaccess file and the `AddHandler` directive with either :-

```
AllowOverride All
```

or

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

Comment: Not working for me. though `<?php` is there. I did google but found same options at all.

Comment: `LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so` already activate

Comment: yes. it is `AllowOverride All` in `apache config` file

Answer (score 0):

My DEV HTACCESS looks like this

```
<IfModule mime_module>
  #AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .shtml
</IfModule>
```

I switch the Hashing for LIVE server though.
Hope this helps