# Uploading html file to server - breaks

Tags: php, html

(First time posting, sorry if formatting is bad :( )

I patched together an html/php page. It works on this live test environment I used phpfiddle.org

[Working there it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNIDT.png)

When I save the code and upload the file to my server (I've tried two servers, same problem on both), [it's broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvSHi.png)

I suspect the problem might be with the header, but I have no clue.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$potErr = $stackErr = "";
$pot = $stack = "";

$p = $s = $g1 = $g2 = $b11 = $b12 = $b21 = $b22 = $b23 = 0;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["pot"])) {
    $potErr = "Pot size is required";
  } else {
    $pot = test_input($_POST["pot"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^\d+$/",$pot)) {
      $potErr = "Only integers allowed (might work with decimals though, I haven't tested it')";
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["stack"])) {
    $stackErr = "Stacksize is required";
  } else {
    $stack = test_input($_POST["stack"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^\d+$/",$pot)) {
      $stackErr = "Only integers allowed";
    }
  }
        $p = $pot;
        $s = $stack;
        $g1 = pow(($p+2*$s)/$p,1/2);
   $g2 = pow(($p+2*$s)/$p,1/3);

        $b11 = ($p*$g1-$p)/2;
        $b21 = ($p*$g2-$p)/2;

        $b12 = $p*$g1*($g1-1)/2;
        $b22 = $p*$g2*($g2-1)/2;

        $b23 = $p*$g2*$g2*($g2-1)/2;
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Geometric Sizing Calculator</h2>
<p>
        <i>Shoutout to AlexMartin&#39;s pokernerdz.com which is unfortunately offline. A quick geo calc in his honor! - Paul lnternet Otto </i>
        </p>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   Pot: <input type="text" name="pot" value="<?php echo $pot;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $potErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Stack: <input type="text" name="stack" value="<?php echo $stack;?>">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $stackErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Geo Sizing:</h2>";
echo "<b>2-street sizing plan:</b> <br>";
echo "Bet " . round($b11) . " then bet " . round($b12) .".";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<b>3-street sizing plan:</b> <br>";
echo "Bet " . round($b21) . " then bet " . round($b22) . " then bet " . round($b23) .".";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Formatting's more than just a little bad.

Comment: I can run the snippet on here actually and it has the same error. Awesome :D

Comment: @chris85 I saved it as .html

Comment: @frosty I put the code here, maybe it's better http://pastebin.com/8qm5EbzK

Comment: Also `^\d+$` says only numbers are allowed; no decimals. Additional there is a built in function, `is_numeric` and `c_digit` to check if the the input is integers.

Comment: Thanks @chris85 that was the problem. Saved as .php and works. Easy :-)

Comment: I've posted a bit more detailed of an answer. Please take a look and if that sounds right please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `html` extension your PHP instance doesn't know to process it, so it doesn't. You can modify your server so `html` and `htm` files are processed as PHP as well; or you can just rename the file to `.php`.

For the latter solution see this thread; [Process HTML files like PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397957/htacess-process-html-files-like-php).