# Server Side Includes putting php in html

Tags: php, html, apache, ssi

I am trying to print the output of php file in HTML using server side includes.
Here is the code of index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <body>
    <!--#include file="include.php" -->
    <h1>This is a Example Of Server Side Includes</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code of my include.php file.

```
<?php
  echo "Hello From PHP\n";
  echo "Hello To HTML\n";
?>
```

Here is the content of my `.htaccess` file.

```
Options +Includes
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

All the files located in **/var/www/html.**

This is the screen shot of while executing index.html.

[image]

Does Server Side Includes also work in localhost? if yes How to configure?
And where to put .htaccess file in var/www/html.

Comment: You're not telling the HTML page to include the PHP page. `<!--#include file="include.php" -->` is commented out, try `<?php include 'include.php';?>` Your new lines also should be `<br>` because a `\n` isnt a new line in a browser. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19398070/4333555

Comment: Should not it be `<!--#include virtual="..." -->` instead of `<!--#include file="..." -->`?

Comment: @akond also tried already, but not working.Thanks

Comment: @chris85 You don't understand what SSI is. The correct way to do it is `<!--#include virtual="/path/to/file.html" -->`.  See this reference (under Additional examples): https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html

Comment: If @akond's solution didn't work, you need to edit your Apache preferences.  See this resource: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html

Comment: @EmmetArries Never done that, also wouldn't since the page is already running PHP why add complexity. Just use the PHP include. The PHP isn't going to execute in a html file so this would fail anyways. Also since the OP asked for an explanation I don't think I was far off.

Comment: @chris85 I understand that PHP includes would be better, and simpler. By no means did I mean to make you feel bad. I just wanted to make it clear for other people that use SSI that your statement about it being commented out was incorrect, because `<!--#include virtual="/path/to/file.html" -->` is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Nginx, an example of how to use SSI (Server Side Includes) is below:

```
<!--# include virtual="/body.php?argument=value" -->
```

[Nginx SSI Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, you need to have a file with the PHP extension. You cannot use PHP in a file with an HTML extension. Change index.html to index.php

Comment: thank you very much. But I can't do that. The business requirement is this. I can't change the names of file.

Comment: `.html` could be used to execute PHP if the handler is modified (close to what the OP is doing).

Comment: Hello @chris85, can you explain it a little bit more.

Comment: @AtulGupta I commented on your question, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If localhost does support ssi, it wouldn't be supported in an html file. Try changing the name to index.**s**html. Also, since your include path is relative, try <!--#include file='...'-->

Or, you could just try what the other answers say, and use php instead.