# Difference between an HTML and a PHP file

Tags: php, html

I have to query a mysql database using php, but a file with the `.html` extension for example my `index.html` does not recognize the
`<?php ?>`.

Now I have `index.php`, what are the differences between this and the `index.html` file?
I can work properly with the `index.php` file or there is a method to insert `<?php //SOME CODE TO MY DB ?>` this type of code into an `.html` file?

P.S.
I know that ajax exists, but in all the tutorials I have seen the file extension was `.php` and not `.html` and I can't understand how to use it.

Comment: You can add `.html` as an extension PHP should process as well. By default it doesn't process them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397957/process-html-files-like-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both text files with code in them.

The difference isn't in the files, but in how your webserver treats them.

It is configured to run files with a `.php` extension though a PHP engine, and to serve up `.html` files directly.

Comment: so there is no problem if i work directly with a file .php, the only problem is that i have to run it with a localhost server like Apache? 
is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the php file through an apache (or other php-handling) server. For instance, if you use XAMPP, and have index.php in the XAMPP directory, you would open a browser and go to localhost/index.php. The server then converts it into html, which a browser can handle.