# How to create a route that ends with .html in Slim Framework PHP

Tags: php, slim-3

I have used Slim Framework several times without any problem but now I'm trying to set a route to match URL that ends with .html and render a certain view, but the framework return a 404 Not Found error, the route is ignored and it seems to me that just checks if there is a file named like that, and since there isn't, simply throw the 404.

The route I'm trying to set is this:

```
$app->get('/{slug}.html', BusinessController::class . ':business');
```

This is possible in Laravel and that's the reason I'm a bit confused. Maybe someone stumbled upon this issue and know a solution.

Comment: Is there any reason in needing the .html?  It probably won't reach slim as it is only part of the processing of php code (just found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397957/process-html-files-like-php which may help)

Comment: Yes, I think I have to set up something on the .htaccess to make it works. The reason is to know that the URL correspond to a business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly to achieve this you will need to disable your web server (apache, nginx or other) from serving static html pages for your project. Typically a url that ends with .html will cause web servers to check for the corresponding static html file.

Then you need to add rewrite logic in `.htaccess` file to make sure all `*.html` routes are passed to your frameworks route handler like `index.php` or `server.php` (*I am not familiar with Slim*). Then its a matter of how you have configured your framework to handle there routes.

Comment: I tried with the .htaccess without success but if you set AddType application/x-httpd-php .html inside the project VirtualHost it works. Thanks!